# Error cam_hal: EV-VSYNC-OVF when using face recognition in esp32-cam

Tags: machine-learning, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

i am using the example 'CameraWebServer' on my esp32-cam board. The upload setting are the listed above:

```
Board:  AI Thinker ESP32-CAM;
CPU Frequency: 240 MHZ ;
Flash Frequency: 80 Mhz;
Flash Mode: QIO.
Arduino IDE 2.0.0
esp32 by Espressif version 2.0.14
```

With those setting i'm able to upload my code , but the fece recognition fuction is not working. When i click in 'enroll face' nothing happens and my Serial Monitor display the message EV-VSYNC-OVF. How to resolve this?

Additionally i already tried unsuccessfully modify the upload seetings and change the parameters config.frame_size and config.xclk_freq_hz in the file 'CameraWebServer.ino'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The sollution was to downgrade from the espressif esp32 board version to 1.0.5 . After that i uploaded to my board set as Wrover Model and then after the upload i changed to the AI thinker board.

Hope it helps.